# DataScroller not rendererd after binding with bean

Tags: jsf-2, facelets, tomahawk

My goal is to reset the first page of the datascroller after a new search.
This should be done with this statement:

```
getTableScroller().getUIData().setFirst(index);
```

My problem is, after I bind the datascroller with a bean it will not be rendered. Just after I hit the search button a seccond time it will be rendered.

Bean:

```
public class HistoryBean {
    private HtmlDataScroller tableScroller = new HtmlDataScroller();
    // ...
```

Facelet:

```
<t:dataScroller id="scroll_1"
                for="data"
                fastStep="10"
                pageCountVar="pageCount"
                pageIndexVar="pageIndex"
                styleClass="scroller"
                paginator="true"
                paginatorMaxPages="9"
                paginatorTableClass="paginator"
                paginatorActiveColumnStyle="font-weight:bold;"
                immediate="true"
                actionListener="#{historyBean.scrollerAction}"
                binding="#{historyBean.tableScroller}"
                >
```

If I remove the `binding` attribute it will be rendered on initial request. What have I forgotten?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't bind the component to a bean which is in a broader scope than the request scope.

Rather specify the `first` attribute just straight in the view.

```
<t:dataScroller first="#{historyBean.index}" ...>
```